# Python Requests / urllib2 Post Login Order

Tags: python, python-2.7, post, python-requests

I'm attempting to make a program that involves accessing a website that is password protected, I have attempted to POST the password and another parameter using Requests and urllib2 both to no avail as they appear to change the order of the parameters in the POST. I can only think that the server is relying on the fact that the parameters are always in the same order and is therefore giving me a 401 authorization required.

This is my current script:

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
login_data = dict(post_password='PASSWORD', Submit='Submit')
s.post('http://www.my_website.com/my_sub/wp-login.php?action=postpass', data=login_data)
```

POST sent from browser:

```
post_password=PASSWORD&Submit=Submit
```

POST sent from Python script:

```
Submit=Submit&post_password=PASSWORD
```

Any information would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: I *highly doubt* the order of parameters matters, but you can tell `requests` to maintain ordering; see [Ordered http request parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13352185) (applies equally to the `data` and `params` arguments).

Comment: The more likely candidates are cookies (request the page with the login form *first*), and / or the headers (`Referer` and `User-Agent` being top contenders).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OrderedDict

```
import requests
from collections import OrderedDict
s = requests.session()
login_data = OrderedDict([('post_password','PASSWORD'),('Submit','Submit')])
s.post('http://www.my_website.com/my_sub/wp-login.php?action=postpass', data=login_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as Martijn pointed out and I just managed to test, the order didn't matter, it was the lack of headers and cookies that was the issue